# finding the average geo location in an array

Tags: php, arrays, geolocation

I'm trying to find one lon lat location from an array where it is part of the average.
So in the array below I have a couple of locations in London, and more location in New York.

I only need one location from New York, but what is the best way to find one lon lat from the array where it is part of the average?

```
$arr = [
    '52.416091, -4.080259',
    '51.481303, -0.456359',
    '51.495893, -0.457115',
    '40.749601, -73.987273',
    '40.747390, -73.997573',
    '40.726188, -74.004096',
    '40.715000, -74.009933',
    '40.645483, -74.078425',
    '40.709366, -73.953075',
    '40.784015, -73.953075'
];
```

Thanks

Comment: Part of the average of what?

Comment: So I don't mind which location in New York I get back, such as '40.726188, -74.004096'. But I want to know most of the lon lats occur within that area and not in London.

Comment: @user2075215 well in that case just count number of NY location (lat < 45) and if so return one such value if not return one value from London

Comment: I don't know what locations are going to be in the array, in this example NY just happens to be the most location in the array

Comment: Use a kmeans with k = 2